# how to add file browser to android app preference

Tags: android, preferences

I would like to add a preference in my android app in which you choose an file and it will return path of the file chosen. I don't want to use intents and want to use [the OpenIntent FileManager](http://www.openintents.org/en/filemanager). How can i add it to my app so it doesnt need to be installed prior to using my app and will technically be installed because it will be a part of my app?

It would be awesome if it only allowed the user to select only a zip file.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want. But you can't implement a non-opensource in your app. You'd need to find a opensource project that you can use as a library. Something like this: https://github.com/nexes/Android-File-Manager
That's my best guess.

Comment: @LordMarty, OpenIntent FM is open source. It's Apache Licensed, too.

Comment: @Vaibhav, you can download the OpenIntents FM source, refactor it so you it won't interfere with with another install of OI, and then invoke it directly by specifying the package name. Note that this is not recommended or desired by the folks behind OpenIntents, but there's nothing from stopping you.

Comment: so what would OI reccomend or desire? I want to do this right.

Comment: and if i decide to do the refactoring thing, would i need to merge the res of my app and the file browser?